# append a element svg inside another svg in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently have a svg that is the main one that contains all my elements. then I have another svg that corresponds to the drawing of a marker. Is it possible within my main svg to add the second svg? If so, what is the correct/best way to add 2 of my markers and modify their size?

the first svg is being created in this line:

```
 const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",250).attr("height",250);
```

the second is the marker..

this is my code:

```
  <body>
  <div id="circles" style="width:100%; height:100%x; border: 2px solid blue"></div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 26900 35810" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill="#D82C62" d="m13406 35810c424-340 9325-12335 10071-13340 1180-1589 2146-2848 2818-5086 2756-9189-4320-17352-12785-17384-9099-34-15490 8788-12948 17248 980 3261 3947 6682 6125 9588l5018 6693c517 689 1266 1582 1701 2281z"/>
    </svg>
  <script type="text/javascript">
          const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",250).attr("height",250);
  </script>
  </body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/aDEo6wSsDVcv4qUIdHVw?p=preview

Comment: It depends: where is the second SVG? Is it an external link?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado sorry! I updated the question

Comment: Ok, so that embedded SVG is the second one? It's already being rendered, you know...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado In short, I would like to know how to add the svg of the marker to the svg that I created dynamically. I would like to do it using the best practice

Answer (score 0):

Or you can actually embed child svg in parent svg like this without d3.js:

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <svg>
            ...
        </svg>
    </g>
</svg>
```